# Tensorflow slim how to specify batch size during training

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use slim interface to create and train a convolutional neural network, but I couldn't figure out how to specify the batch size for training.
During the training my net crashes because of "Out of Memory" on my graphic card.
So I think that should be a way to handle this condition...
Do I have to split the data and the labels in batches and then explicitly loop or the slim.learning.train is taking care of it?
In the code I paste train_data are all the data in my training set (numpy array)..and the model definition is not included here
I had a quick loop to the sources but no luck so far...

```
g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        # Set up the data loading:
        images = train_data
        labels = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels=train_labels, num_classes=num_classes)
        # Define the model:
        predictions = model7_2(images, num_classes, is_training=True)

        # Specify the loss function:
        slim.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(predictions, labels)

        total_loss = slim.losses.get_total_loss()
        tf.scalar_summary('losses/total loss', total_loss)

        # Specify the optimization scheme:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.001)
        train_tensor = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)

        slim.learning.train(train_tensor,
            train_log_dir,
            number_of_steps=1000,
            save_summaries_secs=300,
            save_interval_secs=600)
```

Any hints suggestions?

Edit:
I re-read the documentation...and I found this example

```
image, label = MyPascalVocDataLoader(...)
images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=32)
```

But It's not clear at all how to feed image and label to be passed to tf.train.batch... as MyPascalVocDataLoader function is not specified...
In my case my data set are loaded from a sqlite database and I have training data and labels as numpy array....still confused.
Of course I tried to pass my numpy arrays (converted to constant tensor) to the tf.train.batch like this

```
    image = tf.constant(train_data)
    label = tf.contrib.layers.one_hot_encoding(labels=train_labels, num_classes=num_classes)
    images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=32)
```

But seems not the right path to follow... it seems that the train.batch wants only one element from my data set...(how to pass this? it does not make sense to me to pass only train_data[0] and train_labels[0])

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create the tfrecords which is the special type of binary file format used by the tensorflow. As you mentioned you have the training images and the labels, you can easily create the TFrecords for training and validation.

After creating the TFrecords, all you need to right is decode the images from the encoded TFrecords and give it to your model input. There you can select the batch size and all.